# don't understand this ng-repeat syntax in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I found this code for nested accordion : http://embed.plnkr.co/GvMsP2/

What does (phylum, phylum_examples) in animals mean : what does phylum and phylum_examples contain respectively

```
    <!doctype html>
<html ng-app="plunker">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.1.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://angular-ui.github.com/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.3.0.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
  <div accordion ng-repeat="(phylum, phylum_examples) in animals">
  <div accordion-group class="accord" heading="{{phylum}}">
    <div accordion ng-repeat="(class, class_examples) in phylum_examples">
      <div accordion-group class="accord" heading="{{class}}">
        <div accordion ng-repeat="animal in class_examples">
          <div accordion-group class="accord" heading="{{animal}}">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</div>


  </body>
</html>
```

js:

```
    angular.module('plunker', ['ui.bootstrap']);

function AccordionDemoCtrl($scope) {



      $scope.animals = {vertibrates:
  {mammals: ['lion', 'dog'],
  birds: ['hawk', 'sparrow']},
  invertibrates: {'insects': ['bee', 'ant']}};


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div accordion ng-repeat="(phylum, phylum_examples) in animals">
```

1) phylum is a key for phylum_examples and phylum_examples have an object for that key

2) from phylum_examples

```
(class, class_examples) in phylum_examples
```

class is the inner key for class_examples and class_examples is the object value of phylum_examples

so it will be a like

```
var phylum_examples = {
      class : class_examples
      class : class_examples
}

var array = [
     phylum : phylum_examples,
     phylum : phylum_examples,
     phylum : phylum_examples,
]
```

here phylum , phylum_examples , class & class_examples will be replaced by your actual value